# Async await is not waiting

Tags: javascript

I want my code to wait and let `jsonObj.forEach...` to go through 2 mongodb queries and then go to next (`console.log(branch)`). For this I use async/await but even after that I dont get the required results as course and branch array is printing out to be empty.

```
jsonObj.forEach(async(data)=>{

  try {
    var result = await collections.collection('studentData').find({rollNumber:parseInt(data.rollNumber)}).toArray()
    console.log('--------data---------')
    if (result[0]) {
      course.push(result[0].course)
      branch.push(result[0].branch)
      console.log('-------- entry object ----------')
      await collections.collection('something').insertOne(something,(err,res)=>{if (err){console.log(err)}else {console.log('inserted')}})
    } else {
      console.log('not inserted')
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
)

var title = 'Result is out'
var body = 'Result of' + reqs.body.company
console.log('-------------branch and course--------------')
console.log(branch)
console.log(course)
```

Any idea what is wrong? and how can i get the required result.

Comment: See: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: You need to promesify your callback.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a Promise returning.

```
(data, callback)
```

Then handle the callback.

I highly recommend using this library:

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html